# How to add variable in npm script inside the path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, eslint

I have a monorepo application with a few sub-apps. I want to run the linter only for a specific app and not for the whole repo.
This is the folder structure.

```
├── apps
│   ├── app-1
│   ├── app-2
```

And this is the npm scripts.

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --fix 'apps/$APP_NAME/**/*.{ts,tsx}' --ignore-pattern 'node_modules/'",
 },
```

As you can see, I am trying to add some variable inside the path by command line

```
npm run lint APP_NAME=app-1
```

but it throws an error like

> No files matching the pattern "apps/$APP_NAME/**/*.{ts,tsx}" were
> found.

What's wrong with this approach?

**P.S.**
In an ideal world, I would like to just run `npm run lint app-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env#cross-env-vs-cross-env-shell).

Install the cross-env.

```
npm i -D cross-env
```

Modify `package.json` to:

```
"scripts" {
    "lint:app1": "cross-env APP_NAME=app-1 npm run lint",
    "lint": "cross-env-shell eslint --fix 'apps/$APP_NAME/**/*.{ts,tsx}' --ignore-pattern 'node_modules/'"
}
```

Then run `npm run lint:app1`